# Java - TreeSet and hashCode()

Tags: java, hashcode, treeset

I have a quick question about [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) collections and [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) methods. I have a `TreeSet` and I'm adding objects to it, before I add an object, I check to see if it exists in the `TreeSet` using the [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method.

I have 2 distinct objects, each of which produce a distinct hashCode using my implementation of the hashCode method, example below:

```
public int hashCode()
{
    int hash = 7;
    hash = hash * 31 + anAttribute.hashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 + anotherAttribute.hashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 + yetAnotherAttribute.hashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

The hashCodes for a particular run are: 76126352 and 76126353 (the objects only differ by one digit in one attribute).

The contains method is returning true for these objects, even though the hashCodes are different. Any ideas why? This is really confusing and help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

TreeSet does not use `hashCode` at all. It uses either `compareTo` or the Comparator you passed to the constructor. This is used by methods like contains to find objects in the set.

So the answer to your question is that your compareTo method or your Comparator are defined so that the two objects in question are considered equal.

From the javadocs:

> a TreeSet instance performs all
>   element comparisons using its
>   compareTo (or compare) method, so two
>   elements that are deemed equal by this
>   method are, from the standpoint of the
>   set, equal.

Comment: It also uses the equals method, so it's important that equals and the Comparator/compareTo are consistent.

Comment: "This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method ..." (from http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Comment: this indeed was the problem, I added an extra attribute, updated equals and hashCode but forgot about compareTo. Thanks!!

Comment: what if I am inserting an Integer object in TreeSet and contains() returns false even though an Integer with same value already exists in the TreeSet?

Answer (score 4):

From Java Doc:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, 
>       then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must 
>       produce the same integer result.

Means: the objects you use for hashing are not equal.

Comment: That's assuming hashCode and equals have been defined in a way that does not break that contract.

Comment: @sepp2k This *is* the 'general contract for `hashCode()`'. That's why it uses the word 'must'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" chapter 3.  It explains the equals contract and how to properly override equals, hashCode, and compareTo.

Comment: It's even available online: http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf

Comment: I was all ready to upvote gustafc's comment, but the link is now broken :(

Comment: Go buy the book.  It's still out there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to checked if it is contained, because the insert() basically does the same operation (i.e. searching the proper position) on its way to the insertion point. If the object can't be inserted (i.e., the object is already contained), insert returns false.

Comment: That's one example (like most of the Collection classes) for a very clean and concise API.