# SortedSet - sorting and equality tests not working as expected

Tags: java

I have instances of a class which I'd like to sort in a particular order, but also be able to tell if an instance exists in a set using a *different* criteria. Example:

```
public class Foo {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Foo(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y }

    // equality determined by value of 'x':
    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Foo) {
            return ((Foo)obj).x == this.x;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.x;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Foo foo) {
        if (this.x < foo.x return -1;
        else if (this.x > foo.x return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}

...

// Would like to keep a set of Foos, but sorted by 'y' value.
// Passing in an explicit comparator which sorts on 'y'.
SortedSet<Foo> test = new TreeSet<Foo>(new ComparatorFoo());

public static class ComparatorFoo implements Comparator<Foo> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Foo o1, Foo o2) {
        if (o1.y < o2.y) return -1;
        else if (o1.y > o2.y) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now trying:

```
test.add(new Foo(3, 4));
test.add(new Foo(1, 2));
test.add(new Foo(5, 6));

// sorts by 'y' ok.
for (Foo foo : test) {
    System.out.println(foo.toString());
}

// but can't find an instance with the same 'x' value:
test.contains(new Foo(1, 999));
```

Do I need to keep two separate data structures to do this? (One for sorting, one for equality testing?)

Thank you

------ Update ---------

End result: the comparator used to initialize the SortedSet also gets used when contains() is invoked. Therefore I couldn't have the set sorted by 'y', and check for existence of an element by 'x'.

Comment: How does it compile when you override the compareTo method without implementing Comparable? You do not need this method, provided that you use a Comparator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define your `compareTo` consistent with `equals`

From java doc of [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) check the highlighted part.

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) **must be consistent with equals** if the sorted set is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See the Comparable interface or Comparator interface for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted set performs all element **comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are**, from the standpoint of the sorted set, equal. The behavior of a sorted set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.

Change your comparator like below

```
public static class ComparatorFoo implements Comparator<Foo> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Foo o1, Foo o2) {
        if (o1.x < o2.x)
            return -1;
        else if (o1.x > o2.x)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It will return you `true`

Comment: Man. Didn't actually knew that. +1

Comment: @RohitJain note that your answer was good but sadly it doesn't apply to `TreeSet`/`TreeMap`: [Java - TreeSet and hashCode()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1470735/1065197)

Comment: Correct, but in my case, I'd like to explicitly sort my set by the 'y' value. But I also want to know if an instance exists in the set using a  given 'x' value. It doesn't seem like this is possible when the supplied comparator is sorting by 'y'?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Yeah, I actually didn't knew that, so I though this might be the reason. Thanks for the link though :)

Comment: @user291701: Yes, you will need to maintain two separate data structures -- unless you're willing to do an explicit linear-time search through the iterator instead of using the provided `contains` method.