# Java TreeSet Not Working as Expected

Tags: java, overriding, hashcode, hashset, treeset

I built my own class that implements comparable (maybe not relevant) and when I try using a HashSet to store the items, the HashSet sometimes claims that the item is in the HashSet even though it is not. I thought it had to do with reference checks, but I confirmed that is does not. What is wrong?

Vertex class `equals` and `getHashcode`:

```
public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>{

    // some code ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;
        return this.getPosition().equals(other.getPosition());
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCode1 = Integer.parseInt(this.getPosition().getX() + "" + this.getPosition().getY());
        return hashCode1;
    }
}
```

Position class:

```
public class Position {
    private int x;
    private int y;


    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Position other = (Position) obj;
        return this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //return String.format("x = %d, y = %d", x, y);
        return String.format("(%d, %d)", x, y);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the implementation

```
public static void test(Vertex[][] grid) {
    TreeSet<Vertex> someSet = new TreeSet<Vertex>(){{
       add(new Vertex(new Position(3, 4), false));
        add(new Vertex(new Position(0, 5), false));
    }};
    Vertex v = new Vertex(new Position(2, 5), false);
    if (someSet.contains(v)) {
        System.out.println("error");
    } else {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

The above prints `error`.

Comment: your hashcode is not unique for example it will return same value for two different points i.e. (2,31) & (21,3)

Comment: what are your keys? Are your keys implementing equals and hashcode fully? I

Comment: You should include the code that uses the classes you posted (i.e. the code that creates the HashSet).

Comment: Hashcode doesn't have to be unique, yours is kinda weak tho, try to make it better. Show us how you are using your map, and class for keys.

Comment: please share what are the keys in your HashSet and what are your contents after adding objects

Comment: Too much code, MCVE please http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @NicolasFilotto post has been edited to accommodate

Comment: When you're adding an element  e1 to a HashSet, the HashSet will first check that an element e2 that satisfies  e1.equals(e2)  already exists. If it does, the insert will fail.

Comment: please add also `compareTo`

Comment: @dsp_user doesn't the HashSet first go to the bin with the corresponding hashcode?

Comment: While that may be true (and it is for a HashMap), it stills calls equals and inserts an element based on equals.(see this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E))

Comment: Please stop using the [double-brace initialization trick](http://www.jesperdj.com/2016/07/19/dont-use-the-double-brace-initialization-trick/).

Comment: @Jesper Is this relevant to the problem? (Just curious)

Comment: @NicolasFilotto wow I just realized my problem: My `compareTo` is using a different comparator than my `equals`. Also, TreeSet doesn't use `hashCode`, so it was comparing other aspects of the object.

Comment: so I guess you should either add  `compareTo` and your answer or simply delete your question

Comment: @NicolasFilotto yes. but I'll just add my own answer in case someone runs into the same problems as I did.

Comment: @ljeabmreosn Not directly (that's why it's a comment and not an answer), but you're using the double-brace init trick in your code: `new TreeSet<Vertex>() {{ ... }}`. This trick has some obvious and less obvious disadvantages.

Comment: @Jesper Ah, okay.

Comment: You still did not provide the method `compareTo` of the class `Vertex``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. As @NicolasFilotto pointed out, I did not mention the `compareTo` function. Based on [a past post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470788/6454387), TreeSet **does not** use `hashCode` but rather uses `compareTo` (I assume for binary searching). That is why my test cases were failing.

Answer (score 0):

With your `hashcode` calculation the points `(1,12)` and `(11,2)` will be treated as identical.

See [best-implementation-for-hashcode-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method) for advice on hash codes.

Comment: That doesn't violate the contract of hashCode - two non equal objects are allowed to have the same hashCode. Whether it's a good or bad hashCode is a different issue.

Comment: I understand this, but doesn't Java handle collisions?

Comment: @ljeabmreosn Java handles collision. It would be easier to answer your question if you posted more relevant code.